# make fclean && make all works, make re doesn't

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm working on an advanced makefile that I found in a book. I've got some simple rules inside:
`clean` to delete binaries
`fclean` to delete some extra files too (links to binaries generated by ln)
`all` to make all
`re` to make `fclean` then make `all`

when I do `make fclean` then `make all`, it works perfectly. When i do `make re`, an error occurs:

```
error: unable to open output file '/Users/malberte/work/libft/bin/libft/common/ft_atoi.o':
      'No such file or directory'
1 error generated.
```

So here is my code:

```
$(_MODULE_NAME)_OBJS := $(addsuffix $(_OBJEXT),$(addprefix $($(_MODULE_NAME)_OUTPUT)/,$(basename $(SRCS)))) $(DEPS)
$(_MODULE_NAME)_BINARY := $($(_MODULE_NAME)_OUTPUT)/$(BINARY)$(BINARY_EXT)
$(_MODULE_NAME)_EXPOSE_BINARY := $(_ROOT)/$(BINARY)$(BINARY_EXT)

ifneq ($(_NO_RULES),T)
ifneq ($($(_MODULE_NAME)_DEFINED), T)

_CLEAN := clean-$(_MODULE_NAME)
_FCLEAN := fclean-$(_MODULE_NAME)
_ALL := all-$(_MODULE_NAME)
_RE := re-$(_MODULE_NAME)
_IGNORE := $(shell mkdir -p $($(_MODULE_NAME)_OUTPUT))

.PHONY: all re $(_ALL) $(_RE)
re: fclean all
# re: $(_RE)
# $(_RE): $(_FCLEAN) $(_ALL)

all: $(_ALL)
$(_ALL): $($(_MODULE_NAME)_BINARY)

.PHONY: $(_MODULE_NAME)
$(_MODULE_NAME): $($(_MODULE_NAME)_BINARY)

.PHONY: fclean clean $(_CLEAN)
fclean: $(_FCLEAN)
$(_FCLEAN): $(_CLEAN)
    rm -rf $($(patsubst fclean-%,%,$@)_EXPOSE_BINARY)
clean: $(_CLEAN)
$(_CLEAN):
    rm -rf $($(patsubst clean-%,%,$@)_OUTPUT)

$($(_MODULE_NAME)_OUTPUT)/%.o: $(_MODULE_PATH)/%.c
    @$(COMPILE.c) -o '$@' '$<'
$($(_MODULE_NAME)_OUTPUT)/$(BINARY)$(_LIBEXT): $($(_MODULE_NAME)_OBJS)
    @if [ "$(LIBMERGE)" = "F" ]; \
    then \
        $(AR) r '$@' $^; \
        ranlib '$@'; \
    else \
        libtool -static -o '$@' $^; \
    fi
$($(_MODULE_NAME)_OUTPUT)/$(BINARY)$(_EXEEXT): $($(_MODULE_NAME)_OBJS)
    $(LINK.c) $^ -o '$@'


$(_MODULE_NAME)_DEFINED := T
endif
endif
```

I've tried lot of things, I really don't understand what is happening when I use `make re` and it throws the error above.
Someone has an idea please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this line in your makefile:

```
_IGNORE := $(shell mkdir -p $($(_MODULE_NAME)_OUTPUT))
```

which creates the output directory, as the makefile is being parsed.  Then you run your `clean` target which invokes this recipe:

```
rm -rf $($(patsubst clean-%,%,$@)_OUTPUT)
```

which causes the output directory to be deleted.  Then you run your `all` target which invokes the compiler and asks it to write the output file to `$($(_MODULE_NAME)_OUTPUT)/%.o` but that directory no longer exists.

So the compiler gives you the error:

```
error: unable to open output file '...': No such file or directory
```

If you run `make` twice, then the first time you clean and delete the directory, then when you run `make all` it will run the `_IGNORE` shell command and create the directory again so it will exist.

If you run `make re` one time, then the makefile is only parsed one time and the output directory is only created one time (before it's deleted).

Answer (score 0):

Okay thank you so much. It drove me to think about how a makefile really works, so here is my basic solution, thanks to you:

```
$(_MODULE_NAME)_OBJS := $(addsuffix $(_OBJEXT),$(addprefix $($(_MODULE_NAME)_OUTPUT)/,$(basename $(SRCS)))) $(DEPS)
$(_MODULE_NAME)_BINARY := $($(_MODULE_NAME)_OUTPUT)/$(BINARY)$(BINARY_EXT)
$(_MODULE_NAME)_EXPOSE_BINARY := $(_ROOT)/$(BINARY)$(BINARY_EXT)

ifneq ($(_NO_RULES),T)
ifneq ($($(_MODULE_NAME)_DEFINED), T)

_OUTPUT_TREE := output-tree-$(_MODULE_NAME)
_CLEAN := clean-$(_MODULE_NAME)
_FCLEAN := fclean-$(_MODULE_NAME)
_ALL := all-$(_MODULE_NAME)
_RE := re-$(_MODULE_NAME)
# _IGNORE := $(shell mkdir -p $($(_MODULE_NAME)_OUTPUT))

.PHONY: all re $(_ALL) $(_RE)
re: fclean all
# re: $(_RE)
# $(_RE): $(_FCLEAN) $(_ALL)

all: $(_ALL)
$(_ALL): $($(_MODULE_NAME)_BINARY)


.PHONY: $(_MODULE_NAME)
$(_MODULE_NAME): $($(_MODULE_NAME)_BINARY)


.PHONY: fclean clean $(_CLEAN)
fclean: $(_FCLEAN)
$(_FCLEAN): $(_CLEAN)
    rm -rf $($(patsubst fclean-%,%,$@)_EXPOSE_BINARY)
clean: $(_CLEAN)
$(_CLEAN):
    rm -rf $($(patsubst clean-%,%,$@)_OUTPUT)

$($(_MODULE_NAME)_OUTPUT)/%.o: $(_MODULE_PATH)/%.c | $(_OUTPUT_TREE)
    @$(COMPILE.c) -o '$@' '$<'
$($(_MODULE_NAME)_OUTPUT)/$(BINARY)$(_LIBEXT): $($(_MODULE_NAME)_OBJS)
    @if [ "$(LIBMERGE)" = "F" ]; \
    then \
        $(AR) r '$@' $^; \
        ranlib '$@'; \
    else \
        libtool -static -o '$@' $^; \
    fi
$($(_MODULE_NAME)_OUTPUT)/$(BINARY)$(_EXEEXT): $($(_MODULE_NAME)_OBJS)
    $(LINK.c) $^ -o '$@'


.PHONY: output-tree $(_OUTPUT_TREE)
output-tree: $(_OUTPUT_TREE)
$(_OUTPUT_TREE):
    mkdir -p $($(_MODULE_NAME)_OUTPUT)

$(_MODULE_NAME)_DEFINED := T
endif
endif
```

I added a prerequisite order to the atomic target

```
$($(_MODULE_NAME)_OUTPUT)/%.o: $(_MODULE_PATH)/%.c | $(_OUTPUT_TREE)
```

Here is the rule:

```
.PHONY: output-tree $(_OUTPUT_TREE)
output-tree: $(_OUTPUT_TREE)
$(_OUTPUT_TREE):
    mkdir -p $($(_MODULE_NAME)_OUTPUT)
```

I'll see if I need more adjustments but it seems to be the right way !